# does anything prevents me from storing Doctrine's EntityManger instance in APC?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

umm... silly question.

I know that one can (and should) use APC cache driver with Doctrine ORM.
But I was just wondering if I can also cache entity manager instance itself?
Is there anything that prevents me from doing this:

```
    $em = apc_fetch('em');
    if(!$em){
        $cache = new Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;
        $config = new Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
        $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
        $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
        $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(TRUE);
        $config->setProxyNamespace('MyProject\Proxies');
        $config->setProxyDir(APP_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'proxy');
        $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver('/path/to/lib/MyProject/Entities');
        $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
        $connectionOptions = array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
            'path' => 'database.sqlite'
        );
        $em = Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
        apc_store('em', $em);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work just fine.
Actually we also do cache EM in our projects. Saves some 300Kb:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved this way:

```
$em=unserialize($_SESSION['entityManager']);
$_SESSION['entityManager']=serialize($entityManager);
```

(Actually, I serialize a self developed DAOFactory object, which in turn contains the entitymanager).

That seems to work fine for me.

BTW: I'm not using APC cache because I want every single user to have a separated instance of all the DAO's entityManager and DBALConnection objects.